# Why does ImageResizer not handle extraction of tiff pages if the tiff has pages of differing image types?

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I'm using imageresizer.net in a console app to pull pages out of tiff images, but when the tiff contains pages of differing image types, what imageresizer extracts does not always represent the original page.

I am using the managed API, with this code:
`ImageBuilder.Current.Build(sourceImagePath, destinationImagePath, new ResizeSettings("page=[whatever]"));`

The TIFF image contains...

- Page 1,  image type "Bilevel (white is zero)", compression "Group 3", size "485kb".
- Page 2, image type "YCbCr (2,1 subsampling)", compression "JPEG (old style)", size "11MB".
- Page 3, image type "YCbCr (2,1 subsampling)", compression "JPEG (old style)", size "11MB".
- Page 4, image type "Grayscale (256 grays, black is zero)", compression "JPEG (old style)", size "4MB".

The behaviour I am getting is...

- Extracting page 1 works correctly.
- Extracting page 2 ends up extracting an image of page 1.
- Extracting page 3 ends up extracting an image of page 1, but squashed into a band about 1cm wide on the left hand side of the image, with the remaining image black.
- Extracting page 4 works correctly.

I have also used libtiff.net to extract the same images using [this method](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/convert-color-tiff-to-a-32-bit-system.drawing.bitmap.aspx), which does not exhibit the same fault.

Edit - using this code to test with the Wic decoder:

```
var settings = new ResizeSettings("decoder=wic&page=" + pageNumber);
Config.Current.Plugins.GetOrInstall<WicDecoderPlugin>();
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(sourceImagePath, destImagePath, settings);
```

This works for page 1 & 4 (no change there), but I get an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error for page 2 & 3 when using the Wic decoder.

Edit 2 - converted the bit that's failing to an MVC project to get /resizer.debug:

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      29/06/2012 4:08:14 a.m.

4 Issues detected:

(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.


(Warning):  You are running a hotfix version of the ImageResizer.
            You should upgrade to a released version with an equal or higher version number as soon as possible. Hotfix and release DLLs with the same version number are not the same - the release DLL should be used instead.
            Assemblies marked as hotfix versions: ImageResizer, ImageResizer.Mvc

(Warning):  NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to production use.
            Add DiskCache or CloudFront for production use

(Warning):  Potentially incompatible ImageResizer assemblies were detected.
            Please make sure all ImageResizer assemblies are from the same version. Compatibility issues are possible if you mix plugins from different releases.
            3.2.3 assemblies: ImageResizer, ImageResizer.Mvc
            3.2.2 assemblies: ImageResizer.Plugins.Logging, ImageResizer.Plugins.Wic


You are using paid bundles: Design Bundle

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.MvcRoutingShim.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.WicDecoder.WicDecoderPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.Logging.LoggingPlugin

Configuration:

<resizer>
<plugins>
<add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
<add name="WicDecoder" />
<add name="Logging" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, scale, stretch, crop, cropxunits, cropyunits, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, ignoreicc, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, anchor, dpi, mode, zoom, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 and CLR 4.0.30319.269
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: x86 !! Warning, running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS(AMD64). This will limit ram usage !!
Executing assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe
IntegratedPipeline: False

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.269   Info: 4.0.30319.269
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.272   Info: 4.0.30319.272
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.269   Info: 4.0.30319.269
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.237   Info: 4.0.30319.237
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.RegularExpressions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
Microsoft.Build.Framework                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.237   Info: 4.0.30319.237
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 10.0.30319.1    Info: 10.0.30319.1
CppCodeProvider                          Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 10.0.30319.1    Info: 10.0.30319.1
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.WebPages                      Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.Mvc                           Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.20105.0    
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure             Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.WebPages.Razor                Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.Razor                         Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
App_global.asax.ijrgfwnu                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
PNCC.LimDocumentBuilder.ImageResizerTest Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
WebDev.WebHost40                         Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 10.0.40219.1    Info: 10.0.40219.1
System.Web.Mobile                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
SMDiagnostics                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Xaml.Hosting                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.272   Info: 4.0.30319.272
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.282   Info: 4.0.30319.282
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Activities                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ServiceModel.Activities           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
EntityFramework                          Assembly: 4.1.0.0         File: 4.1.10331.0     Info: 4.1.10331.0
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 3.2.3.766       File: 3.2.3.766       Info: 3-2-beta-3-temp-hotfix-jun-27-2012-9am  Commit: a0f4f1e
ImageResizer.Mvc                         Assembly: 3.2.3.766       File: 3.2.3.766       Info: 3-2-beta-3-temp-hotfix-jun-27-2012-9am  Commit: a0f4f1e
ImageResizer.Plugins.Logging             Assembly: 3.2.2.0         File: 3.2.2.0         Info: 3-2-beta-2  Commit: 3704dd6
ImageResizer.Plugins.Wic                 Assembly: 3.2.2.0         File: 3.2.2.0         Info: 3-2-beta-2  Commit: 3704dd6
NLog                                     Assembly: 2.0.0.0        
System.Web.Abstractions                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Helpers                       Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Web.Routing                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: Have you tried the WicDecoder plugin? GDI does not handle complex .TIFF files very well, but is still the default for many good reasons. Unlike GDI, LibTiff/LibTiff.NET properly implements much of the TIFF spec and most features. No library implements them all. However, LibTiff and LibTiff.NET are gigantic binaries, which kind of outweighs the benefit for most users.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist, Changing `ResizeSettings("page=[whatever]")` to `ResizeSettings("decoder=wic&page=[whatever]")` doesn't change the resulting images, although I hadn't tried that to start with.

Comment: Are you sure WicDecoder is enabled? Does it show up in /resizer.debug?

Comment: Yeah I added the querystring but forgot to add a reference to the dll. Edited my question to show the new code.

Comment: I'm going to need this special .TIFF file to help you further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update 12/12/2012:

The FreeImageDecoder plugin now supports multi-page TIFF files, and uses libtiff internally. This is the suggested way to deal with very complex/rare .TIFF files.

---

**The TIFF format is extremely complex and poorly standardized. Most libraries (like GDI+ (System.Drawing) and WIC (WPF)) only implement a fraction of the standard, let alone the de-facto features and additions.**

To get this level of .TIFF support, you need to use a library *dedicated* to .TIFF support such as [libtiff](http://www.libtiff.org/) or [libtiff.net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/).

**ImageResizer *does* integrate with LibTiff via FreeImage and the FreeImageDecoder plugin, but multi-page support hasn't been implemented yet**.

You're not up a creek without a paddle - there are many ways to solve your dilemma:

1. [Fork FreeImageDecoder](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/freeimage) and add multi-page support. Difficulty: 7
2. Subclass [BuilderExtension](http://documentation.imageresizing.net/doxygen/class_image_resizer_1_1_resizing_1_1_builder_extension.html), override [DecodeStream](http://documentation.imageresizing.net/doxygen/class_image_resizer_1_1_resizing_1_1_abstract_image_processor.html#ae5d188de9b281e6d1885c86f211190d0), and glue in libtiff.net. Difficulty: 5
3. Subclass BuilderExtension, override DecodeStream,  and glue in  libtiff. Difficulty: 10
4. [Post your idea on the UserVoice site and get 30 votes](http://resizer.uservoice.com/forums/108373-image-resizer-v3). Difficulty:?
5. [Pay me to do it](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/custom). Difficulty: 3 (My next available slot is several months from now, however).

There are already 4 example implementations of decoders: ImageBuilder.DecodeStream, PsdReader, WicDecoder, FreeImageDeocoder, and PdfRenderer. The source code for them [is included in the download](http://imageresizing.net/download). The average decoder requires less than 80 lines of code.

Comment: This is a zip with a cut-down version of the file in question and my results using the default decoder. I don't have access to great tiff-editing tools, but although the colour space of the two problematic pages is 24bit RGB in the cut-down version of the real image, the fault still exists. I'm going to use libtiff.net to work around this at the moment (using the method in my question). FYI, the tiff is one of many that are composed of a large number of scanned documents, and I'm converting a subset of their pages to PNG for inclusion in another document.

Comment: I'd encourage you to go with #2, and make it a plugin. It won't be much extra work and could be helpful to anyone else in the same boat. The project really needs community help since it doesn't have significant income; I'm the only full-time developer on the project and it's very challenging.

Comment: I'm not really sure how implementing IEncoder would help if its the decoding of the image that I'm worried about - am I missing something?

Comment: You're not missing anything, I just confused two different questions and answered the encoder one here. I've updated the answer. By the way, decoders are significantly easier than encoders.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt to subclass BuilderExtension, override DecodeStream, and glue in libtiff.net.

Here are my two test tiffs [different size pages](http://minus.com/lbch5irLumoSQQ) & [pages with different colour space](http://minus.com/lboR49aXnS7tlZ). I've compiled against ImageBuilder v3.2.2.

I'm getting a fault when I use the ConsoleApplication project in the ImageResizer v3.2.2 source with the following code. I've run out of time to fix this issue at the moment, so I thought I'd put my progress here in case anyone else wants to take this further.

**My test code**

I think is failing at `ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.PrepareDestinationBitmap()` on line `s.destBitmap = ...` with a *Parameter is not valid.* error. The dimensions are w=9994,h=7102 and I suspect this might be a memory issue - however if I decode the tiff using `DecodeTiffTo32BitBitmap()` first and pass that to ImageResizer as a memory stream the error does not exist. Also, this failure appears for both v3.2.2 and v3.2.3.

```
var Path = @"[whatever]\TiffDecoderTests\";
var c = new Config();      
new TiffDecoder().Install(c);      
c.BuildImage(Path + "different_page_sizes.TIF", Path + "different_page_sizes-page2-TiffReader.png", "format=png&page=2&decoder=tiffdecoder");
```

**My TiffDecoder class:**

```
namespace ImageResizer.Plugins.TiffDecoder
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Drawing.Imaging;
  using System.Globalization;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;

  using BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic;

  using ImageResizer;
  using ImageResizer.Configuration;
  using ImageResizer.Resizing;

  public class TiffDecoder : BuilderExtension, IPlugin, IFileExtensionPlugin
  {
    private static readonly string[] supportedExtensions = new[] { ".tiff", ".tif", ".tff" };

    public IPlugin Install(Config c)
    {
      c.Plugins.add_plugin(this);
      return this;
    }

    public bool Uninstall(Config c)
    {
      c.Plugins.remove_plugin(this);
      return true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetSupportedFileExtensions()
    {
      return supportedExtensions;
    }

    public override Bitmap DecodeStream(Stream s, ResizeSettings settings, string optionalPath)
    {
      var requested = "tiffdecoder".Equals(settings["decoder"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings["decoder"]) && !requested)
      {
        return null; // Don't take it away from the requested decoder
      }

      // If a tiff is coming in, try first, before Bitmap tries to parse it.      
      if (requested || (optionalPath != null && supportedExtensions.Any(ext => optionalPath.EndsWith(ext, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))))
      {
        return this.Decode(s, settings);
      }

      return null;
    }

    public override Bitmap DecodeStreamFailed(Stream s, ResizeSettings settings, string optionalPath)
    {
      // Catch tiff files not ending in an expected extension
      try
      {
        return this.Decode(s, settings);
      }
      catch
      {
        return null;
      }
    }

    public Bitmap Decode(Stream s, ResizeSettings settings)
    {
      return DecodeTiffTo32BitBitmap(s, settings["page"]);
    }

    private static Bitmap DecodeTiffTo32BitBitmap(Stream s, string page)
    {
      s.Position = 0;
      using (var image = Tiff.ClientOpen(string.Empty, "r", s, new TiffStream()))
      {
        SetDirectory(image, page);

        // Find the width and height of the image
        var value = image.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH);
        var width = value[0].ToInt();

        value = image.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH);
        var height = value[0].ToInt();

        // Read the image into the memory buffer
        var raster = new int[height * width];
        if (!image.ReadRGBAImage(width, height, raster))
        {
          return null;
        }

        // Caller needs to handle disposing the bitmap.
        var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

        var bmpdata = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        var bits = new byte[bmpdata.Stride * bmpdata.Height];

        for (var y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        {
          var rasterOffset = y * bmp.Width;
          var bitsOffset = (bmp.Height - y - 1) * bmpdata.Stride;

          for (var x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
          {
            var rgba = raster[rasterOffset++];
            bits[bitsOffset++] = (byte)((rgba >> 16) & 0xff);
            bits[bitsOffset++] = (byte)((rgba >> 8) & 0xff);
            bits[bitsOffset++] = (byte)(rgba & 0xff);
            bits[bitsOffset++] = (byte)((rgba >> 24) & 0xff);
          }
        }

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bits, 0, bmpdata.Scan0, bits.Length);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpdata);

        return bmp;
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the TIFF directory to the first that matches the requested page number, otherwise:
    /// - If page not set OR less than 0, use the first page in the TIFF.
    /// - If tiff has no directories with the "PAGE" tag, use the first frame in the TIFF.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">The image.</param>
    /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// From what I can tell a TIFF image can store any pages in any directory, so the 1st dir 
    /// might not hold the 1st page - this is why we first iterate all frames looking for a PAGE tag.
    /// </remarks>    
    private static void SetDirectory(Tiff image, string page)
    {
      var pageIndex = GetAdjustedPage(page);
      var numberOfDirectories = image.NumberOfDirectories();

      for (short dirNumber = 0; dirNumber < numberOfDirectories; ++dirNumber)
      {
        image.SetDirectory(dirNumber);

        // Ignore pages that might be thumbnails
        var subFileType = image.GetField(TiffTag.SUBFILETYPE);
        if (subFileType == null || subFileType[0].ToString().ToUpper() != "PAGE")
        {
          continue;
        }

        // Stop if page found
        if (pageIndex == int.Parse(image.GetField(TiffTag.PAGENUMBER)[0].ToString()))
        {
          return;
        }
      }

      // Default to the first frame if the page wasn't found.
      image.SetDirectory(0);
    }

    private static int GetAdjustedPage(string page)
    {
      var pageIndex = 1;
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(page))
      {
        int.TryParse(page, NumberStyles.Number, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out pageIndex);
      }

      // So users can use 1-based numbers
      return Math.Max(1, pageIndex) - 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Further testing seems to indicate the `WicBuilder` plugin resolves this issue.

Comment: I believe the error you're getting actually is caused by memory constraints; the given dimensions require 283MB of **contiguous** RAM;  and even if you have gigabytes of free ram, it may be sufficiently fragmented to cause this problem. Rebooting and running the code immediately would probably work.

Comment: Also, FreeImageDecoder now supports multi-page TIFF files, which should be another solution as well.